# No route found for "GET /inscription"

Tags: symfony4

I've been trying to add a form on my blog app. 
I had one controller for the moment and everything were just fine (display my home page, display all articles, display one specific article with it's comments, and create an article). 
I created a new SecurityController to manage the users registration/login etc.
But I can't display the simplest view. 
Here's what I have :

```
class SecurityController extends AbstractController
    /**
     * @Route("/inscription", name="security_registration")
     */
    public function registration()
    {
        $user = new User();

        $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationType::class, $user);

        return $this->render('security/registration.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

registration.html.twig :

```
    {% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

    {% block body %}
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
    {% endblock %}
```

I got the error : No route found for "GET /inscription"
Why is that ? 
Thanks :D

Comment: Hmm that's interesting I wonder if annotations are enabled in `config/routes/annotations.yaml` https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#creating-routes-as-annotations

Comment: They are. So i'm gonna try to create a config/routes.php

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything...

Comment: I've got this when I run php bin/console router:match /inscription  https://i.imgur.com/Zg04wJ1.png